# GPO And Windows Firewall

Tags: group-policy, windows-firewall

New GPO settings are forcing Windows firewall off.  I have a few custom rules set up which are now null and void due to Windows firewall being off. Is there a way that only my user account (not everyone in my group policy group) can keep those custom rules?

EDIT --
Or is their a way outside of windows firewall to prevent certain programs from accessing the internet?  I do not want to block the program itself, just want to deny the program internet access?

Comment: Are you a domain administrator?

Comment: @Steven - Yes, I am

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Edit the GPO that contains the disable firewall setting
2. From properties of the GPO, select security
3. Add you computer account (remember to add computers from object
   types)
4. Once added, tick deny next to "Apply group policy"
5. Save GPO by closing it

Comment: Can you detailed provide specifics on how to do this?

Comment: @ShaunVermaak - can you please provide further instructions?